# Regular Expression failing in REGEXP_EXTRACT within the read_gbq function

Tags: python, regex, google-bigquery, escaping

I’m failing to successfully execute a Regular Expression function (i.e., REGEXP_EXTRACT) within the read_gbq function.

The read_gbq is sourced from the pandas_gbq module.

The import statement in my Python program is:  from pandas_gbq import read_gbq.

The version of pandas-gbq in my environment is:  0.8.0

The Regular Expression is failing, I believe, due to a failure to recognize the black slash Escape character on Double Quotes.

This Regular Expression works fine in Big Query and in an online RegEx Tester using Python (See Below in code section).

Thank you for your time and attention

```
component = 'CO_ORDER_SUMMARY'
def Read_CO_Order_Summary():                            

        query = ('select co.timestamp, co.jsonPayload._userid_ as co_SVOC, co.jsonPayload.response,  \
                 REGEXP_EXTRACT(co.jsonPayload.response, customerOrderId\":\"([^\"]*)\".*) as CustomerOrderID \
        from `exported_logs_v2.mcc_checkout_service_servicelog_20190623` co  '
             'where co.jsonPayload.component = ' '"' + component + '"' 

      'order by co.timestamp, co.jsonPayload._userid_ '
      'limit 1'
                  )

        co_agg = read_gbq(query, projectid, dialect='standard')

        return(co_agg)
co_agg = Read_CO_Order_Summary()

**ERROR MESSAGE**
GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Syntax error: Expected “)” but got string literal “:” at [1:253]
```

```
****************************************
IN REGEX101.com TESTER (using the Python "flavor" setting)
REGEX
customerOrderId\":\"([^\"]*)\".*
STRING
{"lastModifiedDate":"2019-06-23 16:50:18.212","localStoreId":1515,"cartId":"HC100006597310","customerOrderId":"W838207358","
RESULT
Match 1     
Full match  customerOrderId":"W838207358"," 
Group 1.    W838207358
******************* Big Query ******************
SELECT timestamp, jsonpayload._userid_, jsonpayload.response, 
 -- REGEXP_EXTRACT(jsonPayload.response, r'\"customerOrderId\":\"(.*?)\","')  as CustomerOrderID,    ## All 3 of these work 
 -- REGEXP_EXTRACT(jsonPayload.response, r"customerOrderId\":\"(.*?)\",")     as CustomerOrderID  
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(jsonPayload.response, r"customerOrderId\":\"([^\"]*)\".*") as CustomerOrderID  
FROM `exported_logs_v2.mcc_checkout_service_servicelog_201906*`
   where jsonpayload.component like '%CO_ORDER_SUMMARY%'   ##'%CO_ORDER_SUMMARY%'  or   '%CO_SECURE_LOGON%'
     and ( _TABLE_SUFFIX between "23" and "23" )
     and   jsonPayload._userid_ = "0516CFC3D4B001FB0S" 
 order by timestamp asc
```

Comment: Is your query string a valid string?  You look to have several `'` quotes without joining anything together.  Can you modify your function to `print(query)` and make sure that gives you the statement you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion rtenha.  The single quotes are required to create the query string and unbalanced single quotes will be caught by the parser and indicate an "EOL while scanning string literal" warning.  I have no such warning indicated with my quoting.

Comment: Got it.  I was unfamiliar with that method of string concatenation in python.  Note, if `co.jsonPayload.response` is a valid JSON string, you can also use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(co.jsonPayload.response, '$.customerOrderId')`

Comment: Nailed it rtenha !!!  Thanks so much.  I'd still like to understand why REGEXP_EXTRACT function works in Big Query and the regex tester but not in the read_gbq function. Please submit this as an answer so I can give you credit for it.  Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `co.jsonPayload.response` is a valid JSON string, you could use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(co.jsonPayload.response, '$.customerOrderId')`.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `\` character in python strings - just replace `\` with `\\`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I've tried "escaping the escape" already and this did not fix the problem. Again, this RegEx runs successfully in both Big Query and the online RegEx tester.  I believe the single escape character, which should be sufficient, is not being recognized as an escape character.

Comment: Actually you can try save your SQL query to file, then open it in python and execute it. That way it will preserve any wierd character then.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  The code you see is cut from a .py program so I'm not sure what saving it to a different file and then reopening it will accomplish.

Comment: I meant saving raw query string as separate file. If you read it with open() function you won’t loose any character due to escaping wierdness.